# Adjust the MenuBar under Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift

[image]

When I tried to run on different devices, the menuBar on Iphone 8 seems lower than Iphone X, how would I adjust those programmatically for every screen?
This is my code I have for the menuBar

```
customCollectionView = MenuBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y:(navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))
    customCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
    customCollectionView.collectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    customCollectionView.collectionView.delegate = self
    view.addSubview(customCollectionView)
    menubarViewConstraints()
```

function for menuBar constraints

```
func menubarViewConstraints(){
    customCollectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    customCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: (navigationController?.navigationBar.bottomAnchor)!).isActive = true
}
```

Switch form portrait mode to landscape mode:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the view debugger and see what is going on? Is the `navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height` much higher than it's actually displaying on the iPhone X?

Comment: @CharlieFish Yes, On Iphone X, the menuBar aligns a small part on the bottom of the Navigation Controller.

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean the iPhone 8 Plus

Comment: Is the height of the navigation bar exactly aligned to the bottom of it? Or is the nav bar taller than the blue area on one device?

Comment: @CharlieFish Both nav bar bottom on Ip 8 Plus and X align exactly as the botton of the blue area, But Ip X's top menuBar stays on a part of bottom of Nav bar and Ip 8+'s top menuBar has a space between the bottom of nav bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the safe area on the iPhone X (any potentially future iOS devices).

If you change the y position of your init frame call to be the following it should work.

```
y:((navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height)!) + (navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.origin.y) + 30
```

Basically that will take the height of the navigation bar and add the Y origin position and finally add 30 to it.

There might be a better way to achieve this using the devices safe area, but this is the method that came to mind first that seems like it'll work.

Comment: There seems to be one more issue is when I go to landscape mode, the menuBar is lower and it's width doesn't match the width of the navigation bar, how should I fix this?

Comment: @HungNguyen In your `layoutSubviews` function, you should adjust the position of the `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` positions of the menuBar. You should probably rely on things like the parent view width and height and such to achieve that. That is the high level summary of what you want to do. You kinda just have to play with it till it works the way you want. Relying on device measurements and relying on measurements of things that you know are accurate tends to work best instead of hard coding numbers into the system.

Comment: I just updated the code, added the constraint for the menuBar but still doesn't work, I'm I missing something?

Comment: @HungNguyen How doesn’t it work still? It kinda sounds like a separate question but I could be wrong.

Comment: I just added the function for the menuBar constraints, please see the above additional code

Comment: @HungNguyen What is the constraint linked to? The top bar or the super view?

Comment: The constraint is linked to the menuBar

Comment: @HungNguyen Can you try putting a `print` or breakpoint within your `layoutSubviews` function and ensure it's being called?

Comment: Yes I put a print and it's being called

Comment: @HungNguyen Can you show me the code in that `layoutSubviews`?

Comment: `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        print("Layout subview function is called")
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    customCollectionView.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }`

Comment: @HungNguyen That isn't updating the constraints tho.

Comment: I'm not sure why I should adjust the menuBar position in the layoutSubview in stead of creating a setupLayout function and put the constraints in there?

Comment: @HungNguyen Your question and my answer rely on the fact that `30` is the correct value. You do not want to hard code the value 30 in there. Because it will change on portrait vs landscape. So what you really should be doing is setting up a constraint to align the top of that menu bar to the bottom of that nav bar. You really shouldn't be hard coding 30 in there to achieve that. Because you are setting it to be 30 from the top of the display. Not 0 from the bottom of the nav bar.

Comment: Yes in my program, I actually already got rid of the `30` because I realized I don't need that. The problem is the constraint still doesn't work when I created the constraint function for menuBar, which I asked I'm I missing something in the constraint function?

Comment: @HungNguyen That is a completely different question then what you asked then. I can't help without seeing the details I need to answer your question. So I had no idea that you changed that code. I'm not sure how I can help without knowing the details of the state of things, and what you have tried so far. I mean have you tried to use the view debugger to see if that gives any hints about what is going on? Overall it sounds like you are trying to ask a question that is unrelated to your original question. Which causes problems for me because I need more details to help.

Comment: I'm sorry for this confusing you, yes the original problem was solved. But when I tried in landscape mode the menuBar doesn't align properly that's why I asked another question :)

Comment: @HungNguyen Yeah so go onto Stack Overflow and ask a new question, and please include as much detail as possible. Once you do that, link it here, and I'll try to take a look at it. But be sure to provide as much detail as you possibly can to help get better answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51958701/adjust-menubar-programmatically
Here is the link for the new question, please let me know if you need additional information.

Comment: Have you checked out my new question?